# (JavaFX) How to do a "do nothing" while loop

Tags: javafx, while-loop, javafx-webengine

I am new to Java, and I'm trying to do an application that updates multiple links but i want to wait for each link to be fully loaded in order to check the next one.

Here is what I'm trying to do.

```
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;

public class browseController {
    @FXML
    private VBox flowPane;
    private WebEngine webEngine = new WebEngine();

    public void updateLinks() {
        // flowPane has 20+ TextFields that contains different links which awaits update
        flowPane.getChildren().forEach(item -> {
            webEngine.load(((TextField)item).getText());
            while (webEngine.getLoadWorker().getState() != Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                //wait until the page is fully loaded then go for the next item
            }
            // verify if the link is different after update
            if (!((TextField)item).getText().equals(webEngine.getLocation()))
                ((TextField)item).setText(webEngine.getLocation());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You should observe the `Worker.state` property (add a listener) and _react_ when it changes to `SUCCEEDED`.

Comment: See also these [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A230513+%5Bjavafx%5D+WebEngine+Worker.State.SUCCEEDED).

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, @Slaw & trashgod - I tried using the listener but I can't seem to figure a way to make it work

Comment: @ kleopatra - thank you for your advice, i will start looking into it.

Comment: When the previous task succeeds, launch the next task. Keep doing so until there's no more tasks. You need to think in an [event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) fashion; don't use loops here (including `forEach`).